# Postgresql: need to get Json formatted value

Tags: json, postgresql

I wanted to get this JSON value (get total count of `crm_call_log` per user).

```
{series: [{'user_id': 1, 'count': 2}, {'user_id': 3, 'count': 1}], xaxis: ['User1', 'User3']}
```

I have two tables,

**res_users**

```
| id |  name |
|----|-------|
|  1 | User1 |
|  2 | User2 |
|  3 | User3 |
```

**crm_call_log**

```
| id | user_id |                            name |
|----|---------|---------------------------------|
|  1 |       1 |               Did not connected |
|  2 |       1 |                  Call connected |
|  3 |       3 | Call connected, but doesn't won |
```

---

What I tried is

```
select 
    array_to_json(array_agg(B)) 
from (
    select 
        array_to_json(array_agg(A)) as series
    from (
        select 
            user_id as id,
            count(id) as value
        from crm_call_log
        group by user_id
        order by 2 desc
    ) as A
) as B
```

So finally I am getting this output

```
[{"series":[{"id":1,"value":2},{"id":3,"value":1}]}]
```

So anyone help me on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0c2fbdb9a2fcced863dff03db98f474a)

```
SELECT 
    row_to_json(s)                                     -- 5
FROM (
    SELECT 
        json_agg(                                      -- 4
            json_build_object('user_id', user_id, 'count', count) -- 3
        ) as series,
        json_agg(rs.name) as xaxis                     -- 4
    FROM (
        SELECT ccl.user_id, COUNT(*)                   -- 1 
        FROM crm_call_log ccl 
        GROUP BY ccl.user_id
    )s
    JOIN res_users rs                                  -- 2
    ON s.user_id = rs.id
)s
```

1. Grouping the `user_id`s in table `crm_call_log` for counting
2. joining `res_users` to get the `name`s for the `user_id`s
3. `json_build_object` creates the json elements like `{'user_id': 1, 'count': 2}`
4. `json_agg` aggregates the json object from (3) and the user `name`s into json arrays
5. `row_to_json` creates one single json object from the subquery with the column names as keys.

[Postgres JSON aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), [Postgres JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Thanks S-Man, But the output "series" looks like { "1" : 2, "3" : 1 } instead of {'user_id': 1, 'count': 2}